# Add a seach box to an integer column in SP online list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, number

Is there a way to add a search-box for a column with type of Number in a SharePoint online list?

It seems this functionality is only available for columns with the type of "single line of text" when we click on the header then "Filter By".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no SharePoint out of the box (OOTB) way to add the search box in "Filter by" section for number fields.

Also, Search box in "Filter by" section is not limited to only "Single line of text" fields. You can also use it for Person or Group, Calculated, etc. fields.

Answer (score 1):

As a supplement,per my test,the following modern column types have a filter search box:

"Single line of text" and "Person or Group"

The following classic column types also have a filter search box:

"Calculated" and "Task Outcome"